# AngularJS initially fill array with true, one for each in model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to have an array with values, one 'true' for each object in my model.

As you can see in my [JSFiddle - Hardcoded working](http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/Q5WyX/), I have currently hard coded the values, and then it works, i.e. the "level 2" tables being collapsed from start.

```
$scope.dayDataCollapse = [true, true, true, true, true, true];

$scope.dayDataCollapseFn = function () {
    for (var i = 0; $scope.storeDataModel.storedata.length - 1; i += 1) {
        $scope.dayDataCollapse.append('true');
    }
};
```

But when I replace the hardcoded with an empty array and a function (shown above) to populate it for me, meaning appending 'true' for each store in the storeDataModel, it fails. All level 2 tables are expanded from start, but can collapse them by clicking two times (one for adding value to array and one for collapsing).

Have also tried with a "real" function...:

```
function dayDataCollapseFn() {
    for (var i = 0; $scope.storeDataModel.storedata.length - 1; i += 1) {
        $scope.dayDataCollapse.append('true');
    }
};
```

...but I can't get the $scope.dayDataCollapse to populate initally.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pointy got me in right direction...thanks! =)

...and then I solved the last thing.

I forgot that I had used a negation, i.e. data-ng-show="!dayDataCollapse[$index]" since I was using collapse="dayDataCollapse[$index]" first. Then I removed the collapse since it didn't work well together.

Anyhow...since I removed the bang (!) I could also use false instead of true and then of course switch the booleans in the $scope.selectTableRow() function as well.

The last thing was that I had if-else, where the if statement checked if dayDataCollapse was undefined and then an else for the logic. Of course the logic did not trigger first time as it was undefined.

Functions that made it work...:

```
    $scope.dayDataCollapseFn = function () {
    $scope.dayDataCollapse = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.storeDataModel.storedata.length; i += 1) {
        $scope.dayDataCollapse.push(false);
    }
};


$scope.selectTableRow = function (index, storeId) {
    if ($scope.dayDataCollapse === undefined) {
        $scope.dayDataCollapseFn();
    }

    if ($scope.tableRowExpanded === false && $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded === "" && $scope.storeIdExpanded === "") {
        $scope.tableRowIndexPrevExpanded = "";
        $scope.tableRowExpanded = true;
        $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded = index;
        $scope.storeIdExpanded = storeId;
        $scope.dayDataCollapse[index] = true;
    } else if ($scope.tableRowExpanded === true) {
        if ($scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded === index && $scope.storeIdExpanded === storeId) {
            $scope.tableRowExpanded = false;
            $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded = "";
            $scope.storeIdExpanded = "";
            $scope.dayDataCollapse[index] = false;
        } else {
            $scope.tableRowIndexPrevExpanded = $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded;
            $scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded = index;
            $scope.storeIdExpanded = storeId;
            $scope.dayDataCollapse[$scope.tableRowIndexPrevExpanded] = false;
            $scope.dayDataCollapse[$scope.tableRowIndexCurrExpanded] = true;
        }
    }
```

**Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/Q5WyX/)**

---

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop is incorrect. The middle expression is evaluated for true/false, but you've just coded it to be a constant value (well, constant for any invocation of the function anyway). Try this:

```
function dayDataCollapseFn() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.storeDataModel.storedata.length; i += 1) {
        $scope.dayDataCollapse.push(true);
    }
};
```

Your function would have done nothing at all if the model had one element, and locked up the browser with a "slow script" warning if the model had zero or more than one elements.

Also note that you should use `true`, the boolean constant, and not the string `'true'`.

*edit* — also note that it's `.push()`, not `.append()`

Comment: Ah, saw that I had missed the "i <".
I have tried the function and I get the following error: 
TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'append'

Comment: @Pixic oh durr; hold on and I'll update the answer (should be `.push()`)

Comment: I tried that too, but it still does not update the array with a true for every object in the model. I need it to be initialized so all level 2 tables are collapsed from start.
I tried invoking the dayDataCollapseFn from the controller directly but get some error...: TypeError: Cannot read property 'storedata' of undefined

Comment: @Pixic well I'm not familiar with Angular, and I don't know what your data model object(s) look like. That error means that there's no "storedata" property on that object.

Comment: it's at the bottom of the JavaScript section of the JSFiddle provided... $scope.storeDataModel which is a JSON structure.

Comment: @Pixic I'll check the jsfiddle ... [here is an updated version of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duJ5C/) with a couple of other errors fixed.

Comment: Thanks man. It has all expanded when running it but first click collapses all, including the one clicked. Is it possible to get this initialized so all are collapsed from start? (My original question...)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular so I don't know what's going on to make things work like that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the help. =) I hope someone else can help me further with this.